# ScrollView Not Detecting Swipe Events Using Custom SwipeTouchListener

Tags: android, android-scrollview, swipe-gesture

I have a gridview which contains a relative layout with other views. I want to add swipe functionality to it, I have done like below:

```
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            //some action
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft() {
           //some action
        }
    });
```

Here's the `OnSwipeTouchListener` class code:

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 60;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 60;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) onSwipeRight();
                    else onSwipeLeft();
                }
                result = true;
            }
            else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (diffY > 0) onSwipeBottom();
                else onSwipeTop();
            }
            result = true;

        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {}
public void onSwipeLeft() {}
public void onSwipeTop() {}
public void onSwipeBottom() {}
}
```

but I get this warning in android studio:

```
Custom view `ScrollView` has setOnTouchListener called on it but does not override performClick less... (Ctrl+F1)
```

If a View that overrides onTouchEvent or uses an OnTouchListener does not also implement performClick and call it when clicks are detected, the View may not handle accessibility actions properly. Logic handling the click actions should ideally be placed in View#performClick as some accessibility services invoke performClick when a click action should occur.

When the app runs, no swipe events are handled. How do I properly detect swipe and perform actions according to swipe direction? Thanks.

Comment: before calling `return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);` add some `Log.d` with `event` or `MotionEvent#actionToString`, what do you see?

Comment: Logs are not showing

Comment: What am I missing?

Comment: so `onTouch` is not called at all?

Comment: Yes, seems so. Any other way to implement this?

Comment: extend `ScrollView` and override some `View` methods related to `MotionEvent`

Comment: more: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/